# Failed to start LSB: OpenIPMI Driver init script

Tags: boot, 16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 Mate on a Dell Inspiron 5567.
During boot, watching

```
journalctl -b0 --system _COMM=systemd
```

I see:

```
mar 29 09:38:45 ale-Inspiron-5567 systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
mar 29 09:38:45 ale-Inspiron-5567 systemd[1]: openipmi.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
mar 29 09:38:45 ale-Inspiron-5567 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: OpenIPMI Driver init script.
mar 29 09:38:45 ale-Inspiron-5567 systemd[1]: openipmi.service: Unit entered failed state.
mar 29 09:38:45 ale-Inspiron-5567 systemd[1]: openipmi.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mar 29 09:38:45 ale-Inspiron-5567 systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service.
```

What does it mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Another nice way to find this kind of errors: `systemctl --failed`. Seems [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openipmi/+bug/1318317). `lsmod | grep ipmi` output?

Comment: @PabloBianchi - I did not read the whole bug report, but the status is "Fix Released".
Did you try the fix?
Did it not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess your hardware does not have an IPMI chip.  To simply stop the errors during boot

```
systemctl disable openipmi
```

An `LSB` service is not defined natively in systemd.  That reduces the info that systemd can tell you.  In this case, `openipmi` installs the script `/etc/init.d/openipmi`.  It looks like this script has some built-in options to provide info.  E.g. this command outputs driver and device info.  Drivers not loaded and a device that does not exist would suggest the hardware does not have IPMI support.

```
/etc/init.d/openipmi status-all
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openipmi/+bug/1844448).
Note that the error you report is similar to that [in the middle of the thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openipmi/+bug/1844448/comments/5), after some fixes were applied to the initially reported bug.
And further below, [it is reported as fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openipmi/+bug/1844448/comments/7) in openipmi - 2.0.27-0ubuntu1.

So you might need an update of [`openipmi`](https://wiki.debian.org/OpenIPMI).

What are your kernel and openipmi versions?

Comment: openipmi 2.0.22-1.1ubuntu2.1, kernel 4.15.0-142-generic. Doesn't seems to be related to that bug, no "unexpected operator" here.

Comment: @PabloBianchi - Please see EDITed answer. I am not sure you had read the whole bug report thread before. 
And I am not sure it will be easy for you to perform the opemipmi upgrade required to confirm/reject this option.
Please post feedback.